# Need help counting only certain words (Python)

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, python-3.x, count

So far i have written this code:

```
"""test""" 
from collections import Counter
FOR_ = 0
WHILE_ = 0
SAUCE_ = None
IF_ = 0
DEF_ = 0
INPUT_ = input("Enter file or directory: ")
print ("Enter file or directory: {0}".format(INPUT_))
print ("Filename {0:>20}".format(INPUT_))
BEE_ = open(INPUT_)
CEE_ = BEE_.readlines()
CAT_ = (str(CEE_))
FAT_ = CAT_.strip()
with open(INPUT_) as EFF_:
    i = 1
    for SAUCE_ in EFF_:
        if i == (int(2)):
            break
        i += 1
    DEE_ = list((SAUCE_))
NNN_ = (DEE_[8:-4])
GGG_ = ''.join(NNN_)
print ("Author {0:>29}".format(GGG_))
if len(CEE_)<=9:
    print ("lines_of_code {0:>8}".format((len (CEE_))))
elif len(CEE_)>=10:
    print ("lines_of_code {0:>9}".format((len (CEE_))))
COUNTER_ = Counter(str(CEE_))
for LINE_ in CEE_:
    if  ("for ") in LINE_:
        FOR_ += 1
for LINE_ in CEE_:
    if  ("while ") in LINE_:
        WHILE_ += 1
for LINE_ in CEE_:
    if  ("def if ") in LINE_:
        IF_ += 0
        AYE_ = IF_
    elif ("if ") in LINE_:
        IF_ += 1
        AYE_ = IF_
for LINE_ in CEE_:
    if  ("def ") in LINE_:
        DEF_ += 1
print ("for_loops {0:>12}".format((FOR_)))
print ("while_loops {0:>10}".format((WHILE_)))
print ("if_statements {0:>8}".format((AYE_)))
print ("function_definitions {0}".format((DEF_)))
print ("multiplications {0:>6}".format((COUNTER_['*']))) 
print ("divisions {0:>12}".format((COUNTER_['/'])))
print ("additions {0:>12}".format((COUNTER_['+'])))
print ("subtractions {0:>9}".format((COUNTER_['-'])))
```

So far it counts every instance of the words: for, def, if and while. However what i want it do is only count each of these words if they are not preceded by any of these words. for example:

```
for def if
```

would count as ONLY for.

also, i would like anything in the file followed by a hash to be ignored also:

```
#for you
```

would not count as a for.

any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You may want to start by reading [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Is this for a class or something? Why do you have the exact same code as the other question that I linked to?

Comment: No it's not, just something we were working on together but didn't get any helpful answers last time

Comment: @JamesPinson: There are so many corner cases that you have to account for, there's really no point in even trying to write a parser for Python like this (aside from that `for def if` isn't valid Python code). See my answer in that other question.

Comment: Is this being made for fun or to build something on top of?

Comment: This code is not beautiful